# How to use json file as secret file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops, cicd

We are using the newman docker image to run postman collection in Jenkins. command used is : newman run <api_collection_file_name_json> -e <env_file_name>

The environment file will be the json file.

For above implementation, if we create a json file as a secret file in jenkins credential manager and to display the content of the file, we performed the cat operation. As a output , we could see the entire file though it is created as a secret file in jenkins credential manager.

I would like to understand , if we are creating json file as secret file then why it is displaying the content?

Can someone help me to understand if any other approach we can use?

We really appreciate your help and support in this regard.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.